# Existence of general solution of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider two statements. True/False ? Provide an example as well.

1.If an ODE has no general solution then it has finitely many solutions.

2.If an ODE has infinitely many solutions then it must have a general solution.

What I think -
I know that a differential equation does not always possess a general solution . In fact there are infinite equations with no general solution. But the examples I'm considering are ones having no solution like,

|y'| + |y| = c where c < 0.

Can someone explain the statements above with examples .

Comment: What's a general solution?

Comment: If an ODE has no general solution, or at least a local solution everywhere in its domain, is it then still "ordinary"? The second statement is also a little strange, in the direction but not as bad as "if a dog is not an apple, then it has to be a chair".

Comment: If in the example I wrote above I choose c = 1 then can I claim that all constants on the unit circle of the complex plane would be solutions. @LutzLehmann

Comment: Would they count as a general solution ? Or just infinite particular solutions ?

Comment: Or are the statements themselves are not quite right .

Comment: A differential equation is an equation for a function and a finite number of its derivatives, evaluated in one or a finite number of points. To be "ordinary", the function is of one variable and the evaluations have to be at one point only, one could probably add some regularity conditions for the solvability for the highest order derivative.

Comment: A general solution in my understanding would be the flow function, assigning each initial condition a maximal solution. I also do not know how one could get in general an equation with only a finite number of solutions, except the simplistic one of taking the equation with one single solution as you showed, producing some shifted versions and multiplying them up. You might look at Clairaut DE for a class that lies somewhere in-between.